# tkinter resize label width (grid_propagate not working)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, width

I'm having problem with adjusting the width of the label to reflect current width of the window. When the window size changes I'd like label to fill the rest of the width that is left after other widgets in row consume width they need.
Putting the label in a Frame and using *grid_propagate(False)* does not seem to work.
Consider following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class PixelLabel(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, w, h=20, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        creates label inside frame,
        then frame is set NOT to adjust to child(label) size
        and the label keeps extending inside frame to fill it all,
        whatever long text inside it is
        '''
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=w, height=h,borderwidth=1)
        #self.config(highlightbackground="blue")

        self.grid_propagate(False) # don't shrink
        self.label = ttk.Label(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label.grid(sticky='nswe')

    def resize(self,parent,*other_lenghts):
        '''
        resizes label to take rest of the width from parent
        that other childs are not using
        '''
        parent.update()
        new_width = parent.winfo_width()
        print(new_width)

        for lenght in other_lenghts:
            new_width -= lenght
            print(new_width)

        self.configure(width = new_width)

root = tk.Tk()

master = ttk.Frame(root)
master.grid()

label = ttk.Label(master,text='aaa',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')
label.grid(row=0,column=0)

label1_width = 7
label1 = ttk.Label(master,text='bbbb',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken',width=label1_width)
label1.grid(row=0,column=1)

label2 = ttk.Label(master,text='ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')
label2.grid(row=0,column=2)

label3_width = 9
label2 = ttk.Label(master,text='ddddd',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken',width=label2_width)
label2.grid(row=0,column=3)

label4 = ttk.Label(master,text='ee',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')
label4.grid(row=1,column=0)

label5 = ttk.Label(master,text='f',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')
label5.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='we')

nest_frame = ttk.Frame(master)
nest_frame.grid(row=2,columnspan=4)

label8_width = 9
label8 = ttk.Label(nest_frame,text='xxxxx',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken',width=label8_width)
label8.grid(row=0,column=0)

label9 = PixelLabel(nest_frame, 5, text='should be next to xxxxx but is not?',borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')
label9.grid(row=0,column=1)
label9.resize(root,label2_width)

root.mainloop()
```

1. Why label9 does not appear next to label8
2. How to make label9 resize to meet current window size (this code is just a sample, I would like to be able to resize label9 as the window size changes dynamically when functions are reshaping the window)

Comment: Ok, but grid_propagate False prevents Frame to adjust to its child's size. So if I disable it for Frame and say 'keep the size I gave you' and set Label to be sticky'='sw' to that Frame I should get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you are using a label in a frame. I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You can get labels to consume extra space without resorting to putting labels inside frames.  However, since you posted some very specific code with very specific questions, that's what I'll address.

> Why label9 does not appear next to label8

Because you are creating the label as a child of the root window rather than a child of the frame. You need to create the label as a child of `self` inside `PixelLabel`:

```
class PixelLabel(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, ...)
        ...
```

> How to make label9 resize to meet current window size (this code is just a sample, I would like to be able to resize label9 as the window size changes dynamically when functions are reshaping the window)

There are a couple more problems. First, you need to give column zero of the frame inside `PixelFrame` a non-zero weight so that it uses all available space (or, switch to `pack`).

```
class PixelLabel(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ...
```

Second, you need to use the `sticky` attribute when placing `nest_frame` in the window so that it expands to fill its space:

```
nest_frame.grid(..., sticky="ew")
```

Comment: great, that worked! Thanks for explainig it this way rather than saying 'You'd better do it differently:...' - really appreciate it! This was just a sample code and this approach looks like the best way to go in proper app.One thing though: I don't think I need 'sticky="we" ' - I have columnspan=4 so it already takes all the width available (or do I?)

Comment: @simplynail: _"or do I?"_ - try it and see. There are two concepts at play here: being _given_ all the space, and _filling_ all the space.