# grid_propagate doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have reviewed similar questions ([Using grid_propagate(False) in Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117101/using-grid-propagatefalse-in-python-tkinter), [tkinter resize label width (grid_propagate not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401426/tkinter-resize-label-width-grid-propagate-not-working)). But I still can't find out why it's not working. My pink labels in the middle are still resizing.
[image]

This is part of my code. Where should I use grid_propagate?

```
class coursePlan(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.bgcolor='mint cream'
        self['bg']=self.bgcolor
        self.buttonColor='SeaGreen1'
        self.labelWidth=18
        self.buttonWidth=6
        Label(self,text='Time',relief=FLAT,bg='#00ffff',\
              width=self.buttonWidth,height=1).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
        self.aweekday=['m','t','w','r','f']
        self.weekday=['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']
        self.time=['{}:{}0'.format((i//2+7)%12+1,[0,3][i%2]) for i in range(24)]
        for i,date in enumerate(self.weekday):
            Label(self,text=date,relief=FLAT,bg='#00{}ff'.format(hex(250-i*25)[2:]),\
              width=self.labelWidth,height=1).grid(row=0,column=i+1,sticky=NSEW)
        for i,time in enumerate(self.time):
            Label(self,text=time,relief=FLAT,bg='#00{}ff'.format(hex(250-i*5)[2:]),\
              width=self.buttonWidth,height=1).grid(row=i+1,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
        self.timeLabel=Label(self,text='Time:')
        self.timeBox=Entry(self)
        self.exampleText='Example: tr12-1:15'
        self.timeBox.bind('<FocusIn>',self.focusIn)
        self.timeBox.bind('<FocusOut>',self.focusOut)
        self.nameLabel=Label(self,text='Name:')
        self.nameBox=Entry(self)
        self.locLabel=Label(self,text='Location:')
        self.locBox=Entry(self)
        self.boxList=[self.timeBox,self.nameBox,self.locBox]
        for i,(box,label) in enumerate(zip(self.boxList,[self.timeLabel,self.nameLabel,self.locLabel])):
            label.configure(anchor='n',\
                            bg='lavender',\
                            bd=0,\
                            height=1,\
                            width=self.labelWidth//2,\
                            relief=FLAT)
            label.grid(row=i,column=6,sticky=NSEW)
            box.configure(bg='lavender',\
                           bd=0,\
                           width=3*self.labelWidth//2,\
                           relief=FLAT)
            box.grid(row=i,column=7,columnspan=2,sticky=NSEW)
            box.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.switch)
        self.setup()
        self.addButton=Button(self,text='Add',command=self.add)
        self.clearButton=Button(self,text='Clear',command=self.clear)
        self.readButton=Button(self,text='Read',command=self.read)
        self.saveButton=Button(self,text='Save',command=self.save)
        self.colorButton=Button(self,text='Color',command=self.switchColor)
        self.fontButton=Button(self,text='Font',command=self.switchFont)
        buttonList=[self.addButton,self.clearButton,self.readButton,self.saveButton,self.colorButton,self.fontButton]
        for i,button in enumerate(buttonList):
            self.configureButton(button)
            button.grid(row=i//2,column=9+i%2,sticky=NSEW)
        Label(self,text='Course List',relief=FLAT,bg='DeepSkyBlue',\
          bd=0,width=2*self.labelWidth,height=1).grid(row=3,column=6,columnspan=3,sticky=NSEW)
        self.read()

    def putLabel(self,datetime,name,loc,mode=0):
        ## part of the code for the pink label
        for weekday in datetime[:weekindex]:
            day=self.weekday[self.aweekday.index(weekday)]
            label=Label(self,text=name+'\n'+loc,bg=self.colorList[0],font=self.fontList[0],\
                        bd=0,width=self.labelWidth,height=grids)
            self.courseLabels[index].append(label)
            label.grid(row=self.time.index(start)+1,column=self.weekday.index(day)+1,rowspan=grids,sticky=NSEW)
            label.grid_propagate(False)

    def switchFont(self):
        self.fontList=self.fontList[1:]+[self.fontList[0]]
        for lst in self.courseLabels:
            for label in lst:
                label['font']=self.fontList[0]

root=Tk()
cp=coursePlan(root)
cp.pack()
root.title('Schedule')
root.mainloop()
```

When I tried self.grid_propagate(False) in the **init** function, I got this.

[image]

And when I tried root.propagate(False), the size of window is fixed, but the labels in it are still resizing.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to relevant code.

Comment: which pink label do you mean ? There are only pink labels. And for me they seems OK.

Comment: what is `self.labelWidth` ? Maybe it has wrong size ? Or maybe you should use `grid_propagate(False)` with `Frame` like in links which you add in question - `self.grid_propagate(False)`. BTW: instead of `0` use `False` and it will be more readable.

Comment: @furas I mean the pink labels on the left, the labels in the schedule. I tried using self.grid_propagate(False) but I got a blank window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid_propagate` should be called on a parent widget rather than a child widget. If you're putting a widget in `self` and don't want that widget to cause `self` to resize, the you need to call `self.grid_propagate(...)`.

Comment: I also tried that at the end of __init__ but I got a blank window.

Comment: @SeakyLone: that's not surprising. The documented behavior of `grid_propagate` is to set whether or not the size of a widget is controlled by its children. You didn't give `self` a size, and you say that you don't want the labels controlling the size, so the size is going to remain small. What you probably need to do is put these labels inside a frame rather than in the same parent as all the other widgets.

Comment: So I have to calculate the size of self and set it, then the size will not change?

Comment: I just tried self['height']=25 and self['width']=200, which has the same height and is wider than my current window. However, when I used grid_propagate, it only displayed a super small part of it.

Comment: @SeakyLone: my suggestion is to start over. Layout problems are best solved one at a time, and you're trying to juggle too many widgets. Start with a blank window. Add a frame to contain your grid, and then just one or two widgets to the grid, nothing else. Get all of that working before adding anything else.

Comment: Do you mean use self.frame=Frame(master) instead of inheriting from Frame? I tried but it's still resizing.

Answer (score 1):

> *"grid_propagate doesn't work"*

From the code you've provided, it's indeterminate whether or not it works. [`grid_propagate`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) is for setting or unsetting the flag to allow/disallow its object(`label` in this case) to resize based on its child(ren)'s demands of size. `label` has no children in above case so `grid_propagate` has no meaning.

Perhaps read on [`grid_rowconfigure`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) and [`grid_columnconfigure`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method).

In below demonstration `main` `restart`s each time <kbd>Escape</kbd> is hit with `grid_propagate` option is set randomly as `True` or `False` for `root` to randomly allow/disallow `root` to resize based on its child(ren)'s, only `label`'s in this case, demands of size. If it's `True` then `root` is allowed to resize based on its child, `label`'s, size demand; If it is `False` then `root` isn't allowed to resize based on its child, `label`'s, size demand, which is the reason why the `label`'s text content is cut in half, initially:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def restart(event):
    global root

    root.destroy()
    main()

def main():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()

    label = tk.Label(root, bg='pink')
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    grid_prop_val = random.choice([True, False])
    label['text'] = str(grid_prop_val)
    label['text'] += ", also a long enough sentence to notice resizing."
    root.grid_propagate(grid_prop_val)

    root.bind('<Escape>', restart)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I rebuilt a simple program that used root.grid_propagate(False) and it did work. However, I still couldn't understand why it doesn't work for my original code. And I also make my code a bit more complete. Could you please check that out?

Comment: @SeakyLone It _does_ work for your program, both the earlier and newer version. It's just I don't think it does what you believe it does. Are you certain you've read both answers here?

Comment: Do you mean I should use grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure instead of grid_propagate?

Comment: @SeakyLone Not necessarily. However, I suspect those may be the methods that are closer to the behavior you want. But that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to Nae for the clear explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356468/16716984)  This "answer" is simply a modification to his code that brought it more in line with my issues.  So, just the results and the code.

[Propagate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPS9y.jpg) [!Propagate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syMJi.jpg)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *      
import random


def restart(event):
    global root
    root.destroy()

    main()

def main():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.focus_force()
    root.configure(bg='red',width=200,height=200)
    content1=Canvas(root,bg='green',height=100)
    content1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    content1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    content1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    content2=Canvas(root,bg='aqua',height=100)
    content2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    content2.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    content2.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    label1 = tk.Label(content1, bg='pink',text='pink ')
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    label2 = tk.Label(content2, bg='yellow',text='yellow ')
    label2.grid(row=0, column=0)

    grid_prop_val = random.choice([True, False])
    label1['text'] += str(grid_prop_val)
    label2['text'] += str(grid_prop_val)
    content1.grid_propagate(grid_prop_val)
    content2.grid_propagate(grid_prop_val)

    root.bind('<Escape>', restart)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```